# Exporting to PDF from DataGridView using FastReport in Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, pdf, fastreport

I'm having problems with exporting my values in my DataGridView to PDF using FastReport.

I believe I have the correct code for it, but the rows in my PDF doesn't seem to be  updating, it only displays the first row of my DataGridView.

```
private void CreateDataSet()
    {
        ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.TableName = "ABCD";
        ds.Tables.Add(table);
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dg.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                table.Columns.Add(dg.Columns[i].HeaderText);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < dg.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(dg.Rows[j].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(), dg.Rows[j].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString(), dg.Rows[j].Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString(), dg.Rows[j].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(), dg.Rows[j].Cells[4].FormattedValue.ToString(), dg.Rows[j].Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

I even tried removing the `For` Loop and replacing it with this:

```
table.Rows.Add(dg.Rows[0].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(), dg.Rows[0].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString(), dg.Rows[0].Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString(), dg.Rows[0].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(), dg.Rows[0].Cells[4].FormattedValue.ToString(), dg.Rows[0].Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString());
table.Rows.Add(dg.Rows[1].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(), dg.Rows[1].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString(), dg.Rows[1].Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString(), dg.Rows[1].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(), dg.Rows[1].Cells[4].FormattedValue.ToString(), dg.Rows[1].Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString());
```

But no avail.

Here's the output for the code above in PDF: http://i1296.photobucket.com/albums/ag2/paozaf/output_zpsde2b6278.png

Desired data output: http://i1296.photobucket.com/albums/ag2/paozaf/desiredoutput_zps44a27fac.png

Comment: your question is not very clear ..where is the PDF export issue ? are you having trouble exporting or filling the dataset ?

Comment: Okay, sorry. I have added the print screen of the output and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your issue (it only displays the first row) is empty value of DataBand. You should assign data for it.

```
Report report = new Report;
report.Load("reportTemplate.frx");
report.RegisterData(dataSet);
report.GetDataSource("tableName").Enabled= true;
DataBand db = report.FindObject("DataBand1") as DataBand;
db.DataSource = report.GetDataSource("tableName");
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Td8J.png)